# BottomSheetDialog get Behavour always returns null

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, behavior

I working with **BottomSheetDialog** and i have to get Behavior so can set **setBottomSheetCallback()** to handle some stuff.

As [google says](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) i had to put Coordinator on parentView and add behavior to it. I defined CoordinatorLayout in MainActivity (root activity) like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:tag="coordinatorLayout"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"

...
```

This is try to get from activity:

```
 public void setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style) {

 CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
 BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(coordinatorLayout);
```

I also tried:

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout); 
//this is point to the coordinatorView 

BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(coordinatorLayout);
//But this returns same error that "The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout"
```

As you see i passed the coordinator-layout but method can not find behavior in it.
I also should mention to points in using **BottonSheetDialog**:

1. I show my BottonSheetFragments like this:
2. I inflated my **BottomSheetDialog** in OnCreateView (not in setupDialog()) for ability of adding View Pager inside. As you may know ViewPager wont attach to BottonSheetDialog if you inflate view in **onSetupDialog()**.

Any way i could not get behavior of CoordinatorLayout of parent. 
In my bottonSheetDialog i try these methods and non of them works and i get **"The view is not a child of CoordinatorLayout"**  error.

code for **point 1**:

```
MyFragment myFragment= MyFragment.getInstance(bundle);
myFragment.show(fragment.getChildFragmentManager(),"tag");
```

code for **point 2**:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottomsheet, null, false);  
return rootView;
}
```

Comment: `BottomSheetDialog` is kinda weird. It's not actually added to your `CoordinatorLayout`. It goes fullscreen, with a transparent background, and sets up its own `CoordinatorLayout` internally, and the bottom sheet is added to that. It also sets its own private `BottomSheetCallback` on it, and you can't really interfere with that. Can you instead set up your own `View` with `BottomSheetBehavior`?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the source code again, the only thing the callback does is `cancel()` the `Dialog` in `onStateChanged()` if  `newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN`, which you could handle yourself in your own callback. If you wanna try that, calling `findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)` on the `BottomSheetDialog` will give you the internal `FrameLayout` that has `BottomSheetBehavior`.

Comment: @MikeM. Let me check.

Comment: @MikeM. I want to get the behavior to get onStateChange() to handle and move between another open dialogs. As you told there is internal Behavior? How i can get that?

Comment: You'd call `BottomSheetBehavior.from()` on the `View` returned from `bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)`.

Comment: What is design_bottom_sheet? You mean my Activity rootView Coordinator layout?

Comment: No, specifically `R.id.design_bottom_sheet`. It's the ID of the internal bottom sheet `FrameLayout` in the `BottomSheetDialog`. It's defined in the design library. You don't need to define that ID.

Comment: OK, I was just doing some testing, and it seems you'll have to set the callback _after_ the `Dialog` is shown. Here's my quick test: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ycnVkwM7DVNE9PVrcv00d1NYQaEblc35/view?usp=drivesdk. It's working for me, so lemme know if you have an issue.

Comment: You know i tried to handle this all inside my class, not on outside method. And unfotunately (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) inside setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style)  returns null. As i mentioned in question i do not used dialog.setContent() instead inflate view in onCreateView. It became headache now. I updated the part of question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "my class". Are you subclassing `BottomSheetDialogFragment`? If that's what you mean, override `onStart()`, and do it there, after the `super.onStart()` call.

Comment: Yes i have base class that need to handle all stuff there. I find out that when i use setContent() it works and can get behavior without use of setContent( inflateView in onCreateView ). But there for I can not use viewPager. So i had to find a way that get that behavior. I wonder why google docs i mentioned is not works.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you're saying, there. If it helps, here's my previous test in `Fragment` form: https://drive.google.com/file/d/133uS1-uZRwWCqqH1gpkzUi5Mco6ABwMZ/view?usp=drivesdk. That's working just fine for me, too.

Comment: It is worked. It is very odd. when i call getDialog().findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) in setupDialog() it returns null, but as i call it in onStart it works and not null.

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant. I thought that `setupDialog()` method you showed was in your `Activity`. Yeah, `setupDialog()` in the `Fragment` is too early. It won't have created its `View` yet.

Comment: So what about CoordinationLayout and behavior flag on child view. It seems all stuff handled with inner items that i never initialize them.

Comment: `BottomSheetDialog` takes care of setting up its internal `CoordinatorLayout`. There is a `FrameLayout` inside of that which gets the `BottomSheetBehavior`, and the `View` you return from `onCreateView()` is added inside of that `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Thanks. very use full. I think now you can post the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`BottomSheetDialog` is a rather peculiar `Dialog` implementation. It is not added to, nor does it rely on<sup>*</sup>, a `CoordinatorLayout` in your `Activity`'s layout. It sets up its own `CoordinatorLayout` internally, and within that, a `FrameLayout` with `BottomSheetBehavior`, into which your `View` is placed. The `BottomSheetDialog` itself fills the whole screen, and has a transparent background, so that it can handle the bottom sheet interaction, and any outside touches.

If you need access to that bottom sheet and its `BottomSheetBehavior`, we'll need to get it from the `Dialog`'s `View` hierarchy. That's as simple as calling `findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)` on the `Dialog`, but we'll need to wait until the `Dialog` is shown to modify the `BottomSheetBehavior`. Furthermore, since `BottomSheetDialog` sets its own `BottomSheetCallback`, we must ensure that we replace it appropriately. That is, we must take care of cancelling the `Dialog` when it hits the closed state. For example:

```
final BottomSheetDialog bsd = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
bsd.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
bsd.show();

FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) bsd.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            // This is the crucial bit.
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                bsd.cancel();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {}
    }
);
```

If you're using a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, the `Dialog` is shown in `DialogFragment`'s `onStart()`, and we can override that method to do our modifications there, after the `super` call. For example:

```
public class MyFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FrameLayout bottomSheet = getDialog().findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                    // This is the crucial bit.
                    if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                        getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {}
            }
        );
    }
}
```

In either case, you can do pretty much whatever you want in the `BottomSheetCallback`, as long as you `cancel()` the `Dialog` in `onStateChanged()` when `newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN`.

---

<sup>*Incidentally, this means that you do not have to have a `CoordinatorLayout` in your `Activity`'a layout to use `BottomSheetDialog` or `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, though I'm not sure that's made clear anywhere in the documentation or other developer resources.</sup>

Comment: Complete and useful.

Answer (score 0):

in your CoordinatorLayout you have child that have this `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"`

so you need to make `BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(your CoordinatorLayout child);`

And on it you need to make setBottomSheetCallback.
`behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(...)`

Comment: My main activity rootView is child of CoordinatorLayout with that behavior.

Comment: What is the root layout of main activity?

Comment: As i described in question, it is CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: if i understand correctly CoordinatorLayout inside CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"` must be on some child of CoordinatorLayout

Comment: No, my root view is CoordinatorLayout ( in rootActivity). I have another CoordinatorLayout inside parentFragment that BottonSheetDialog is shown. I updated the question.

Comment: No i do not mean that. There is no onShow() method in BottomSheetDialogFragment.

Comment: It is very odd.When  I add getDialog().findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) in on setupDialog() and retun null but when i call it onStart as you mentioned, it worked. It was answer. thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer was not complete. But thanks for your try :)