# Accessing BottomSheetBehaviour from BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I want to set the peek height of bottom sheet dialog fragment but I cant define the bottom sheet behaviour in fragment can anyone help me?

getDialog() returns null in oncreateview method

```
public class ExampleFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment{

 @NonNull
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_itemlist, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

 BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) getDialog();
                FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
}
}
```

Comment: `BottomSheetDialog` does some adjustments to that `Behavior` right before it's shown, so you can't really modify it until after it's been shown. Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53362605).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it in onCreateDialog

Here is the code:

```
 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    dialog.setOnShowListener(dialogInterface -> {
        BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialogInterface;

        FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior bsb = BottomSheetBehavior
                .from(bottomSheet);

        bsb.setPeekHeight(56/*Your height*/);

    });

    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt give null pointer exception but I cant set peek height or state.It doesnt work.

Comment: Try this for setting the state: bsb.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

Comment: onCreateDialog never called. I use it with oncreateview is it normal?

Comment: I normally inflate the layout in onCrateView and expand the dialog in onCreateDialog. Do you inflate your layout in onCreateView?

Comment: Yes I infilate but I call bottomsheet fragment in Activity with replace. My code is "getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.bottom_sheet_fragment, exampleFragment).commit();"

Comment: I'm showing my dialog like this: MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(); myDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "myDialog");

Comment: Yes but I have to change content of bottomsheet with different fragments.

Comment: Inflate different view for each case.